# Convert QPair to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qvariant

I have the following problem: I want to transmitt data via TCP, and wrote a function for that. For maximum reusability the function template is `f(QPair<QString, QVariant> data)`. The first value (aka `QString`) is used by the receiver as target address, the second contains the data. Now I want to transfer a `QPair<int, int>`-value, but unfortunately I can not convert a `QPair` to a `QVariant`. The optimum would be to be able to transfer a pair of `int`-values without having to write a new function (or to overload the old one). What is the best alternative for `QPair` in this case?

Comment: You could use QStringList instead of QPair to host the two integers. QStringList can be converted to QVariant.

Comment: Ok, that's a simple solution, I should have known that for myself -> head -> desk...

Comment: Yiiikes @ _string_ list for an _integer_ pair!

Comment: @arc_lupus any chance you mark this as resolved ?

Comment: @totem: Thanks for remembering me!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use the special macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` to make custom types available to `QVariant` system.
[Please read the doc carefully](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) to understand how it works.

For QPair though it's quite straightforward:

```
#include <QPair>
#include <QDebug>

typedef QPair<int,int> MyType;    // typedef for your type
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType);       // makes your type available to QMetaType system

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...

    MyType pair_in(1,2);
    QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(pair_in);
    MyType pair_out = variant.value<MyType>();
    qDebug() << pair_out;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I completely missed the `value<T>()` in the `QVariant`'s documentation since I am actually using a pair to deliver some `QAction` data. Your post is much appreciated. +1

Comment: According to the QMetaType docs some types are automatically registered and don't need this macro: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum including QPair<int,int>

Answer (score 4):

**Note: this answer uses another functions to convert them, something you may consider.**

You could use `QDataStream` to serialize the `QPair` to `QByteArray` and then convert it to `QVariant`, and you can the inverse process to get the `QPair` from a `QVariant`.

Example:

```
//Convert the QPair to QByteArray first and then
//convert it to QVariant
QVariant tovariant(const QPair<int, int> &value)
{
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream stream(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream << value;
    return QVariant(ba);
}

//Convert the QVariant to QByteArray first and then
//convert it to QPair
QPair<int, int> topair(const QVariant &value)
{
    QPair<int, int> pair;
    QByteArray ba = value.toByteArray();
    QDataStream stream(&ba, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    stream >> pair;
    return pair;
}
```